# Array of pointers, changing pointer elements

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

If I declare an array of pointers like that:

```
    char* arr[5] = {"Mercury",
    "Mercury",
    "Venus",
    "Earth",
    "EArth"};
```

Can I then change sings in those pointers?
I have tried doing something like that

```
*(*(arr + 1) + 1) = 'i';
```

but it doesn't work, I get memory dump.
Is there a way to do that or I have to declare it differently?

Comment: Things such as `"Mercury"` are string literals. Trying to modify a string literal results in undefined behaviour, most of the time a seg fault.

Comment: Each of the 5 pointers in the array points to a string literal. These are constant data, and cannot be changed.

Comment: String literals in C are usually stored in read-only memory. If you allocate read-write memory, either on the stack by declaring an array, or on the heap with malloc, you will be able to modify the strings.

Comment: OT: `*(*(arr + 1) + 1) = 'i';`--> `arr[1][1] = 'i';` but it is still **illegal code**

Comment: You cannot change the contents of the string literals, but you can assign to the array elements to make them point to something else, e.g.: `arr[1] = "Vulcan";`.

Comment: You CAN swap pointers, e.g. `char *tmp = arr[2]; arr[2] = arr[0]; arr[0] = tmp;` would be fine. That would result in the ordering `"Venus", "Mars", "Mercury", "Earth", "Pluto"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to do that or I have to declare it differently?

```
char* arr[5] = {"Mercury", "Mars", "Venus", "Earth", "Pluto"};
```

`arr` is an array of 5 `char` pointers to string literals.
 Any attempt to modify a string literal invokes undefined behavior, so you can´t modify them.

If you want to modify the content you need f.e. to define them as two-dimensional array of `char`s:

```
char arr[5][10] = {{"Mercury"}, {"Mars"}, {"Venus"}, {"Earth"}, {"Pluto"}};
```

and use

```
strcpy(arr[0], "Uranus");

size_t len = strlen(arr[0]);  
for(size_t i = 9; i > (len + 1); i--)  // To remove all left characters from prev. string.
{
    a[0][i] = '\0';
}
```